# Display GPS Coordinate every time in Resume phase

Tags: android, gps

Goal:
Every time I run resume I would like to see the new location by using GPS's coordinate

Problem:
Based on the picture, it doesn't work and I also retrieve "GPS status changed to Temporarily_unavailable".
What part am I missing?

Thank you!

Info:
*I'm new in android
*I'm using API 23

[image]

---

android manifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".SimpleGPSTestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

---

SimpleGPSTestActivity.cs

```
package com.jfdimarzio.test3;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;



public class SimpleGPSTestActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView texten = null;
    private LocationManager location_manager;
    private LocationListener location_listener;

    private void print(String text) {
        Time now = new Time();
        now.setToNow();
        String timeString = now.format("%H:%M:%S");
        String line = timeString + ": " + text + "\n";
        texten.setText(texten.getText() + line);
        texten.invalidate();
        texten.postInvalidate();
    }

    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        texten = new TextView(this);
        texten.setText("");
        setContentView(texten);

        print("onCreate");


        /*
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);


        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive
        // location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
*/

        location_manager =
                (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        location_listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
                double altitude = location.getAltitude();
                print("New location: Long " + dec.format(longitude) +
                        ", lat " + dec.format(latitude) +
                        ", accuracy " + dec.format(accuracy) +
                        ", alt " + dec.format(altitude));
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                print("Location provider has been disabled.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                print("Good news! Location provider has been enabled.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                                        Bundle extras) {
                if (status == LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE)
                    print("GPS status changed to OUT_OF_SERVICE.");
                else if (status == LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE)
                    print("GPS status changed to TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE.");
                else if (status == LocationProvider.AVAILABLE)
                    print("Good news! GPS status changed to AVAILABLE.");
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        print("onPause");
        location_manager.removeUpdates(location_listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        print("onResume");
        try {


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);


            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.


                return;
            }

            location_manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, location_listener);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            print("Couldn't use the GPS: " + e + ", " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
    {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }
            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not giving the LocationManager enough time to get a location to return to you. In clear view of the sky, with GPS [warmed up](http://www.gsmarena.com/glossary.php3?term=gps) (which it almost always is), it takes about 5-10 seconds to get a location update. In other situations, it can take a lot longer or potentially never if you are underground or somewhere where there is no GPS. From the looks of all this, you seem to open then close the Activity immediately after, which starts then stops the update.

Comment: Thank you for your help!